# Neo4j 2.2.3 ClassNotFoundException: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager

Tags: maven, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

This is my Maven config for Neo4j:

```
    <properties>
        <neo4j.version>2.2.3</neo4j.version>
    </properties>

    <!-- neo4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-enterprise</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-ha</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
        <classifier>tests</classifier>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-io</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
        <classifier>tests</classifier>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-lucene-index</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

During the application startup I have a following exception:

```
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions@30bb7d0d' failed to initialize. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:489)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.init(LifeSupport.java:72)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:106)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:331)
    ... 127 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/neo4j/kernel/impl/transaction/XaDataSourceManager
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.ProxyGenerator.generateClassFile(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.ProxyGenerator.generateProxyClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyClassFactory.apply(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyClassFactory.apply(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.WeakCache$Factory.get(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.WeakCache.get(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getProxyClass0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions.getKernelExtensionDependencies(KernelExtensions.java:119)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions.init(KernelExtensions.java:62)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:483)
    ... 130 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 145 more
```

I can't find where `XaDataSourceManager` is located.

Comment: What version of SDN are you using?

Comment: SDN version 3.4.0.M1

Comment: I had this problem with version mismatch between a spring dependency and Neo dependency, but not with 3.4.0.M1. In your case, unless there was something specific in 2.2.3 you wanted maybe you could use 2.2.2 and raising a bug with the Neo team.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't use 2.2.2 because I'm waiting for 2.2.4 .This is my another issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31701307/spring-web-security-locks-neo4j-embedded-database/31746180#31746180

Comment: Well that sucks! Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Xadatasource is present in the neo4j-kernal jar, but with jar version before 2.2.2. Since you are using 2.2.3, you will not find the class in the jar. I think the jar versions you are using are not compatible. Try adding the parent jar and let it reference to the compatible ones.

Comment: Why it is not present in the 2.2.3 ? What is the correct way of using embedded Neo4j Enterprise 2.2.3 ?

Comment: The same functionality may be done by other class. Try with a reduced version unless you need specific feature of 2.2.3

Comment: Neo4j contains errors in a previous versions, I'm also waiting for 2.2.4 release

Comment: Also why two references of **<artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>**

Comment: The second one with a "test" classifier. I need it for using TestGraphDatabaseFactory class

Comment: Try using only this and see if it fetches other dependencies. You can give your own version   **<dependency>
  <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>neo4j-enterprise</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>**

Comment: the same story with 2.2.3

Comment: ok as last try, you can change the version and provide only one artifact

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve dependency of type:org.neo4j.kernel.api.KernelAPI on 2.0.1

Comment: Ok given your situation, until someones comes up with answers for correct usage, you can try adding each dependency and see, if your are facing error. i hope you understood how maven works. We need to give basic dependencies and it will fetch the others required in your project.

Comment: thanks Ramzy, I hope it can be fixed for 2.2.3 version also

Comment: I have solved this error by disabling HA mode - .setConfig("org.neo4j.server.database.mode", "SINGLE")

Comment: You can update your question, with the finalized answer and where you have modified. happy Learning